# Import variable from module imports only first occurrence

Tags: python, tkinter, python-import

In module1.py, I have a variable, var initialized to an empty string. A function in module1 changes the value of this variable. When I import this variable from module2.py, it only reflects the initial state before the function had changed it, even though I made sure to call the changing function before starting the import.

module1.py

```
class App(Frame):
    global nums
    nums = []
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, background='lightgreen')
        self.parent = parent
        self.vcmd = parent.register(self.validate)
        self.centerWindow()
        ............
```

and this is where it gets updated, by a function in same class

```
nums.append(self.b_eq)
```

However, on importing **nums**, I still get an empty array

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701972/python-global-variables-in-multiple-files/29702401#29702401

Comment: Can you clarify the type of the value in your global variable? Is it a string (as the text suggests) or a list (as the code suggests)? How are you importing the variable in your second module? With `from module1 import nums` or `import module1` (followed by accesses to `module1.nums`)? Is there a reason to use a global variable rather than a class variable (or even an instance variable)? Do you have a particular reason for creating your global variable using a `global` statement in a class declaration (which I didn't think would work, but it does!), rather than a top-level statement?

Answer (score 0):

Python modules act as singletons.  If you want to change the value you could either have the function return a result and then call that function.  Or, you could create a class in Module1 and instantiate an object.  From there you can set the value as desired.