# How do I import and change a value from one script to another in python?

Tags: python, project

At the moment I am coding a digital ATM in python. I encountered the problem when I wanted to create a user with a customizable value of balance, but in a different python script file(lets call this file B). In a function in the main script file it changes the imported value. The problem is that the value in file B does not change. What can I do to get this done?

So some variables are in Swedish. Hope it dosen't bother!

File A

```
def overfor():
overforingsInput = float(input('Hur mycket vill du överföra?\n'))
if User1.saldo - overforingsInput > 0:
    User1.saldo - overforingsInput
print '-', overforingsInput, 'kr\n', 'Ditt saldo är nu', User1.saldo, 'kr'
```

File B

```
class User1:
userName = 'felsaf'
userPin = 1234
saldo = 150
```

Comment: 1) Please include the relevant parts of your code to illustrate the problem. 2) Tell us *why* you want the value in B to change. What is the idea behind this?

Comment: Provide your code, along with expected behaviour and actual behaviour.

Comment: do you mean http://stackoverflow.com/a/29702401/2141635?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just import the other module instead of the variable:

a.py:

```
balance = 4711
```

b.py:

```
# do NOT use:
from a import balance
balance = balance + 1

# DO use:
import a
a.balance = a.balance + 1
```

But probably a method in module `a` would be more appropriate than just tempering with other modules globals:

a.py:

```
_balance = 4711

def get_balance():
    return _balance

def set_balance(new_balance):
    _balance = new_balance
```

Or in a concurrent environment:

```
from threading import Lock

_balance_lock = Lock()

class BalanceStale(Exception):
    pass

def set_balance_if_known_value_is_still_current(old_value, new_value):
    with _balance_lock:
        if _balance != old_value:
            raise BalanceStale('{} != {}'.format(_balance, old_value))
        else:
            _balance = new_value
```

Comment: Thats is what I've done, but no success... Let me add my code and lets see what i've done wrong.

Comment: Once imported values are separate, so all users of `a.balance` have to use `a.balance` instead of an imported (stale) `balance`. So better use a "getter" function in `a`:  `def get_balance: return balance`. In `a` add a leading underscore to `_balance` to show that other modules should not import the variable.