# Global Variables between different modules

Tags: python, methods, module, global

**main.py:**

```
from module import *   
var=10

def func2():
    print "func2:" ,var

def main():
    global var
    var=20
    print "main - before", var
    func2()
    func1()
    print "main - after", var

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

**module.py**

```
from main import *

def func1():
    global var
    print "func1:", var
```

The program prints:

> main - before: 20
>
> func2: 20
>
> func1: 10
>
> main - after 20

'var' is a global variable. I would expect that the moment I change var's value, it will be changed wherever the variable 'var' appears. 
The only difference between func1 and func2 is that func1 is in another module. Still, I don't understand why the value of 'var' is different between func1 and func2.

Comment: If you want a global variable across modules http://stackoverflow.com/a/29702401/2141635

Comment: If your architecture or software-design requires circular dependencies between modules, try to re-think it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as a truly global variable in python. Objects are bound to variables in namespaces and the `global` keyword refers to the current *module* namespace. `from somemodule import *` creates new variables in the current module's namespace and refers them to *somemodule*'s objects. You now have two different variables pointing to the same object. If you rebind one of the variables, the other ones continue to reference the original object. Further, a function.s "global" namespace is the module it is defined in, even if it is imported to a different module.

If you want a "global" variable, import the module and use its namespace qualified name instead of rebinding individual variables in the local namespace.

Here's an annotated example...

*cfg.py*

```
var = 10
somelist = []
var2 = 1

def show_var2():
    print var2
```

*main.py*

```
import cfg
from cfg import *   # bind objects referenced by variables in cfg to
                    # like-named variables in this module. These objects
                    # from 'cfg' now have an additional reference here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print cfg.var, var
    var = 20        # rebind this module's 'var' to some other value.
                    # this does not affect cfg's 'var'
    print cfg.var, var

    print '----'
    print cfg.somelist, somelist
    somelist.append(1)    # update this module's 'somelist'
                          # since we updated the existing object, all see it
    print cfg.somelist, somelist

    print '----'
    var2 = 2
    print var2, cfg.var2, show_var2() # show_var2 is in cfg.py and uses its
                                      # namespace even if its been imported
                                      # elsewhere
```

Comment: and what happens when we use "import somemodule" ?
Is it correct that in this case we do NOT create a new variable that points to the same object, so we just use the same variable that was created in the original module?

Comment: @CrazySyntax - exactly. The import create a new reference to _somemodule_. Modules are containers for their global variables (internally, the module namespace is a _dict_) so everyone referencing a variable through the module sees the same variable. If a variable is reassigned (`somemodule.var = "new value"`) all code referencing `somemodule.var` sees the same variable and thus the new value.