# Python: Change variable value from another thread

Tags: python, multithreading

Why does the value of my_string not change?

I'm running two threads from two different modules, and module 2 accesses the "set_string" of module 1 in order to change the value of "my_string", but when module 1 prints the string, its empty.

First module:

```
from threading import Thread
import Module2 as M2
import time

my_string = ""


def set_string(string):
    global my_string
    my_string = string


def mainloop1():
    global my_string
    while True:
        print("Module 1: ", my_string)
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = Thread(target=M2.mainloop2)
    thread.start()
    mainloop1()
```

Second module:

```
import Module1 as M1
import time
import random


def mainloop2():
    while True:
        string = str(random.randint(0, 100))
        print("Module 2: ", string)
        M1.set_string(string)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the methods are implemented in different modules and [there are no *truly* global variables in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914488/global-variables-between-different-modules); the set_string referenced in Module2 is updating the my_string variable in its globals()['M1'] name where-as Module1 is updating the my_string variable stored directly in globals()['my_string'].

Note that if you move your definition of mainloop2 into Module1, update the imports, and the Thread call then you get your expected behavior, indefinite execution order and all.