# Common Globals in several files

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to define globals that can be accessed from several files.
I also have the challenge that when I define the global I have a dynamic name. i.e.

```
name = 'PCOLL2_SCULPT_P1_X'
value = 12
```

So I define the global as

```
 globals()[name] = value
```

and I can then

```
  print(PCOLL2_SCULPT_P1_X)
```

from the defining file, but I don't seem to be able to access from another python file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global Variables between different modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914488/global-variables-between-different-modules)

Comment: why not just do `PCOLL2_SCULPT_P1_X = 12` in main file and then in other files do `from main import PCOLL2_SCULPT_P1_X`?

Comment: Because I don't know the details. The info of variable name and value have to be read in from a file.

Comment: In that case @KeithSloan I would consider reading in that link of the duplicate, and consider using [`configParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) or something similar. I recently used that for setting general params for the whole program which I initialize from a file

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are defined per module (*.py file). From documentation [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals):

> Return a dictionary representing the current global symbol table. This is always the dictionary of the current module (inside a function or method, this is the module where it is defined, not the module from which it is called).

So you can't access them like this.

If you want to have same form of configuration available for different modules then using [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) should be clean solution.

Comment: Okay thanks - will restructure so all globals are in one file and anything that needs access does so via a function defined in the shared/global file

Answer (score 0):

Modifying a bit your code might work. Let's say we have:

a.py:

```py
name = 'PCOLL2_SCULPT_P1_X'
value = 12

globals()[name] = value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(PCOLL2_SCULPT_P1_X)
```

And b.py:

```py
from a import *

print(PCOLL2_SCULPT_P1_X)
```

Running any of those 2 files will print `12`.

b.py could also be:

```py
import a

print(a.PCOLL2_SCULPT_P1_X)
```

**But**, this is not very good, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32915882/6045800). You should examine your use-case carefully and find the best approach.