# Why does my module not behave like a singleton?

Tags: python

I have a JSON file that I am using as a datastore in a small game I am using as a way to learn Python.
I am proficient in a number of other languages.

I have several classes that want read access to the JSON so I want to load the JSON from the file into a variable and then allow the other classes to access the variable via getters and setters, because each class wants different parts of the JSON.

This sounds like a job for a Singleton.  I understood that a Python Module behaves like a singleton.

However, when I import the Module into my classes the variable resets?

Here is a very cut down example:

Module:- state_manager

```
x=45
def set_x(value):
    x=value

def get_x():
    return x
```

Class:- Game

```
import Player

import state_manager
value = state_manager.get_x()
```

Class:- Player

```
import state_manager
state_manager.set_x(12)
```

By setting breakpoints I can see that when Player is imported by Game that `Player` sets the value of `x` in `state_manager` to 12.

But when I look at the value of `x` returned to Game using `state_manager.get_x()` I get 45.

Why is this?

What is the correct way in Python to create a Module or Object that can be shared among other classes?

I realise I can construct a Singleton myself but I thought I'd use the features of Python.

Comment: Maybe this post can help you, they present a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914488/global-variables-between-different-modules

Comment: @AlessiaM That link refers to a decidedly different issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> By setting breakpoints I can see that when Player is imported by Game that Player sets the value of x in state_manager to 12.

I am fairly sure that you're doing something wrong in your inspection, because the `set_x` function, at least as you quoted it...

```
x=45
def set_x(value):
    x=value
```

...does not do what you think it does. Since `x` is being assigned to in the scope of `set_x`, it does not refer to the global (module-level) variable `x`, but to a local variable `x` that is immediately discarded as part of the stack frame when `set_x` returns. The existence of static assignments is effectively how local variables are declared in Python. The fix is to declare `x` as referring to the global variable:

```
x=45
def set_x(value):
    global x
    x=value
```

Comment: I just ran my code again with a break point below x=value (i stuck in a dummy line y=5 just to have a place to put the break point and the x in x=45 really did change to 12.
However, adding the suggested global x did solve my problem so I am inclined to think that my IDE may be misreporting.

Comment: @Richard210363 In that case, there's probably something wrong with your debugging tools, because `x` is decidedly a local variable when used in that manner.

Comment: Our comments crossed over :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare `x` global in any function that attempts to set it globally:

```
def set_x(value):
    global x
    x=value
```

Without the global declaration, `x` is just a function-local variable.

In general, if a function assigns to a variable, anywhere in the function, then that variable is local unless it is explicitly declared `global` (or `nonlocal`).  If a function only reads a variable, without setting it, then the variable is taken from a higher scope (e.g., a global, or an up-level reference).

Comment: `global` or `nonlocal`.

Comment: @EcirHana I edited my answer to mention `nonlocal`.