# How to assign a variable within a function to be referenced in later in code?

Tags: python, function, variables, variable-assignment

I am having some issue calling a function from another file to set a variable in my current file, looking for help.

This works:

```
def myfunc():
  global x
  x = "fantastic"

myfunc()

print("Python is " + x)
```

Correctly prints 'Python is fantastic'

This doesn't work:

File1.py

```
def myfunc():
  global x
  x = "fantastic"
```

file2.py

```
from up2levels.up1level.file1 import * 

myfunc()

print("Python is " + x)
```

result: 'x is not defined'.
I want this result to be 'Python is Fantastic'

What am I missing here? Thanks for the help!

EDIT: I've tried some of the answers and still run into issues, they work in the very dumbed down example but, but I cant get it to work with my code. Here's what I'm trying to do: iterating over a data frame looking for certain parameters to show up (for loop). Once parameters are met, pass line of data frame into function (File1.py) to return 5-6 different variables and record them in File2.py.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Global Variables between different modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914488/global-variables-between-different-modules)

Comment: `x` is a global variable *in the `file1` module*. You need to use `file1.x` in file2.py.

Comment: It's not interesting to use global variables such that. You could just return `x`…

Answer (score 0):

> File1.py

```
def myfunc():
    x = "fantastic"
    return x
```

> File2.py

```
import File1 

print("Python is " + File1.myfunc())
```

Answer (score -1):

```
x = 'fantastic'
```

in a function sets the variable locally.

use `globals()` to set variables globally.

```
def myfunc():
    globals()['x'] = 'fantastic'

myfunc()

print("Python is " + x)
```

I hope it'll useful for you.

Comment: If he wants to add variables without returning and other ways, yes.