# Global Variable across modules

Tags: python, python-module

I faced this problem while i was expirementing with my project.My project is designed so it has multipule submoudles.

Now each submodule needs a position of an the same item on the screen,which is random each time the program ran.I thought it was a good idea to check once where is the position of the item (It does not change in runtime) , and let all modules access the position.(Since checking the position takes a long time)

This is what i did:

## **main**.py

```
import Config
import sub_module

main()

def main():
    position = get_pos()
    Config.pos = position
    sub_module.click_on_item()
```

## Config.py

```
pos = None
```

I tried using this code , so when i ran the program , it sets the `config.py` module `pos` variable , to the position of the item on screen.
This code works fine **but** when i try to use it in the submodules like this:

## sub_module.py

```
import Config

def click_on_item():
    click(Config.pos)
```

It resets the value to None , since it reruns the `Config` module code.
Is there an elegant solution for this problem ? I can't let the position as an argument for the , since my case is much more complex.

One solution that i can think of is writing to the disk , and rereading but it's not fast.

Thanks for the help.

## 2 EDIT:

My project is multi-package , and there is the problem 
this is the directory tree:

```
mainPackage:
    __init__.py
    Config.py
    main.py
    b.py
    Packages:
        Package_A:
            __init__.py
            a.py
```

## main.py

```
import Config
from Packages.Package_A import a
import b

def main():
    Config.Position = (124, 586)
    a.print_val()
    b.print_val()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## Config

```
Position = None
```

## b.py

```
import Config

def print_val():
    print Config.Position
```

## a.py

```
from mainPackage import Config

def print_val():
    print Config.Position
```

## output

```
None -> from Package_A
(124, 586) -> from b.py
```

Sorry for the inconvenience since i didn't know what was causing the problem , my interest is in multi package global variable.

Comment: The premise of your question, shown in this line: "It resets the value to None , since it reruns the Config module code" is simply wrong. Python doesn't rerun modules that are imported more than once. You original code should work as shown. Are you sure you were not doing `from Config import pos` in your real `sub_module.py`? Because that does fetch the value of `pos` at `sub_module`'s import time, rather than at the time the `click_on_items` function is called. (You also show `main()` getting called before it's defined.)

Comment: Are you trying to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701972/python-global-variables-in-multiple-files/29702401#29702401?

Comment: does it reruns it once per import  ? Yes i'm just doing import Config .The code above is just an example , not the actual code

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham yes this is what im trying to do , but it doesn't work in my code - i will relook in a bit

Comment: Why don't you just import the value from the  main  after you have initialised it? That will mean any calculation is done once

Comment: Well that what my example shows , its just the default None value that i have it in the Config , even though i tested it and it does set the value , its just get somehow reset when it changes modules

Comment: Write a working example that shows the problem! You've made some small mistake that we can help you with - but not if you are just dumping garbage non-working examples that you didn't bother running yourself. I notice in your _main.py_ that you call `main` before you define it. That can't work. How can we spot the real mistake with so many others?!

Comment: @tdelaney I Have added the example

Comment: The problem is that the variable is called `Config.Position` not `Config.pos`!

Comment: @DavidBarishev, yes after all that you have a typo, you may want to delete the question

Comment: @tdelaney I'm Sorry , i added another example which shows my case , i have finally pinpointed the problem , please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in *a.py*: `from mainPackage import Config`. You did an absolute import from a package and ended up importing `Config` twice. Python only imports a module once but in your case you used two different names (`Config` in some files, `mainPackage.Config` in others) which confused python and it imported the module twice - once by a package relative import and once by an absolute import. Add `print "Importing Config"` to *Config.py* and you will see it printed twice.

Just change *a.py* to `import Config` and all will be well.

Answer (score 0):

`Config.py` will only be initialized on import once in your application and `pos` will be initially `None`.

`main.py` then sets it, and all other modules can access `pos` with `Config.pos`.

---

#### `Config.py`

```
# Initial value
pos = None
```

---

#### `main.py`

```
import Config
import sub_module

def main():
    position = get_pos()
    Config.pos = position
    sub_module.click_on_item()
```

---

The rest of your files can be kept as is.

**UPDATE**

As @tdelaney mentioned in his answer.

Change

```
from mainPackage import Config
```

to

```
import Config
```

to avoid another `Config`.

Comment: Take a look in my example

Comment: @DavidBarishev You have renamed `pos` to `Position` in `Config.py` and try to access `Config.pos` which is not there anymore.

Comment: I'm Sorry , i added another example which shows my case , i have finally pinpointed the problem , please take a look

Comment: @DavidBarishev See tdelaney's answer.

Answer (score -1):

For each of your module, define your functions/class with a 'pos' argument.

**Module A.py**

```
def foo(pos):
    click(pos)
```

**Module main.py**

```
def main():
    position = get_pos()
    A.foo(position)
```

In general, do not use global var.

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution , it's a viable option , but is there anyway rather than adding it as an argument ? Because it's not that simple

Comment: @DavidBarishev then give a [mcve] that actually reflects what you're trying to do - it's unlikely that globals are the right solution.