# Call variable across different files in Python and dealing with circular imports

Tags: python

I am currently building a docx/pdf converter in Python, and have decided to split up the files into 2 documents:

**`main.py`** - controls the program's flow;

**`convert_to_text.py`** - contains the function that converts pdf/docx files to txt.

At the moment, I am having difficulties passing the global variable `cv` across both files and importing all of the functions in `convert_to_text.py` to use in `main.py`. This is the error I get:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe D:/cv-parser/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/cv-parser/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from convert_to_text import *
  File "D:\cv-parser\convert_to_text.py", line 1, in <module>
    from main import cv
  File "D:\cv-parser\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    document_to_text("resources\CV.pdf")
NameError: name 'document_to_text' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How do I fix it?

This is my code so far:

In **`convert_to_text.py`**

```
from main import cv
import docx
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from cStringIO import StringIO


def document_to_text(filename):
    if filename[-5:] == ".docx":
        doc = docx.Document(filename)
        full_text = []
        for para in doc.paragraphs:
            full_text.append(para.text)
        global cv
        cv = '\n'.join(full_text)
        return cv
    elif filename[-4:] == ".pdf":
        return pdf_to_txt(filename)


def pdf_to_txt(file_path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = file(file_path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos = set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password, caching=caching,
                                  check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    fp.close()
    device.close()
    str = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    global cv
    cv = str
    return cv
```

In **`main.py`**

```
from convert_to_text import *

cv = 0

document_to_text("resources\CV.pdf")
print cv
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using global variables between files in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files-in-python)

Comment: I think that the names might be reversed.

Comment: @AndréLaszlo - thanks for noticing, I've fixed this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701972/python-global-variables-in-multiple-files/29702401#29702401

Comment: It looks like you have circular imports. Anything that both scripts need should be abstracted out into a third file for both to import. There are tricks to make circular imports work, but they're more effort than they're worth.

Comment: @skrrgwasme not sure I follow, what is it in my case that needs to be abstracted out into a third file to import?

Comment: @methuselah read your traceback. `main -> convert_to_text -> main`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only thing you need from `main.py` is `cv`, you should simply pass `cv` in to the functions that need it. And since the functions don't actually *use* `cv` (other than to set it), there's no reason to do that either.

Your whole problem can be solved by simply removing the import of `main`, and using the return value of the function to set `cv`:

```
cv = document_to_text("resources\CV.pdf")
```

Comment: Yup, this is a better answer. I didn't read the code closely enough... removing the "global" variable is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You have a circular import that needs resolved. This is your script's execution path:

1. main.py starts
2. main.py attempts to import everything from the convert_to_text module, triggering evaluation of convert_to_text.py
3. convert_to_text.py attempts to import the main module, triggering main.py's evaluation *again*

But the evaluation of main.py at this point is halted at trying to import the convert_to_text module, so `cv` *doesn't exist yet*. When this error is hit, the interpreter bails and throws the NameError exception.

In general, you want to avoid having two scripts import each other. That's called a **circular import**. There are ways to make circular imports work, but it's more often an indicator of a poorly designed program. I have yet to see an example of a circular import that cannot be refactored into a better organized program.

In this case, the variable `cv` is used by both of your modules. You have at least two possible solutions:

1. Fix your function call structure to correctly pass and return arguments. This code doesn't look like it has a real need for `cv` to be referenced in both modules. See Bryan Oakley's answer for an example. He pointed this out before me.
2. If you have an unhealthy attachment to the use of a global variable, you can refactor your code to move `cv` into a third module that both main and convert_to_text can import, resolving the circular import.

Comment: Haha, was just about to click "Post your answer" but you beat me to it. Our answers have _exactly_ the same structure, almost word by word. :)